# proxy.config.json won't work after I run command ng-build. (Angular V15)

Tags: angular, api, angular-material

Here is my proxy.config.json file
`

```
{
"/apiservices/\*":{
"target":"https://partners.api.skyscanner.net",
"secure":false,
"changeOrigin":true
}
}
```

`

Here is my angular.config.json file inclusion

`

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
          },
```

`

Here is my services.component.ts file methods

`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  header= new HttpHeaders({
    'x-api-key':'prtl6749387986743898559646983194',
  });
  
  fetchLocale(){
    return this.http.get('/apiservices/v3/culture/locales', {headers: this.header})
  }

  fetchCurencies(){
    return this.http.get('/apiservices/v3/culture/currencies', {headers: this.header})
  }
  fetchMarkets(){
    return this.http.get('/apiservices/v3/culture/markets/en-GB', {headers: this.header})
  }
}
```

`

This Code is Working fine on 'ng serve' but won't work after I Build my code, Can anybody tell me What I have to do.

Comment: `/apiservices/\*` seems suspect to me. Can you replace it with : `/apiservices/*` ?

Comment: Also `partners.api.skyscanner.net` does not seem to exist. Or, if you are working at skyscanner, it can be an intranet service only. In that case, check your VPN connection